# Resetting form removes HTML 5 validation on input file

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have encountered this problem and still have no clue/idea about this.

This is my code:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="file" required />
    <br/>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, clicking "Upload" will trigger HTML validation on file input and a error message will be shown.

But if I select a file then click "Reset" button to reset the form. After that, I click "Upload" (submit form), the validation is gone.

I also tries using javascript method `reset()` but the problem still remained.

Note that I use Google Chrome browser.

Does anyone have some ideas about this issue?

Or have I just encountered a bug of HTML validation?

Comment: What is the validation your talking about is it something you have go t or written to check validation and what are you validating?  The EG is hard to go on sorry

Comment: he is talking about the only required input (type=file) ... it can not be empty

Comment: Which browser you are using? And try to check error console for any javascript error. As you jsFiddle demo is working with in Firefox

Comment: There is no js involved in order to reproduce this problem ... plz pay attention and check the jsfiddle Chirag

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I am talking about actual code, fiddle is just example of it. As his jsFiddle code is working fine with in FF

Comment: @ChiragVidani doesn't work on Chrome. My guess is it is a browser bug, that you will have to find a workaround for.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a bug with Chrome.
You can see the difference by adding the below CSS on input field.

```
input:invalid {
    color: blue;
}
```

When you reset on FF, the input field becomes invalid but on Chrome, it does not.  On Chrome, if you select a file and then bring up the select screen again then cancel it, the field becomes invalid. That seems like the only way to reset the input field.

Looks like you will have to add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Only browser I had problems with this was on Chrome. The below would fix the issue for me (not sure why it works)

```
$("button[type='reset']").on('click', function() {
    $("#file").replaceWith('<input id="file" type="file" required />');
    return true;
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2HEL/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this is a bug of browsers (tested on Chrome, Safari, IE 11). Anyway, I will do some javascript work-around to solve this issue.

Comment: @mr.d Hopefully it will get fixed in chrome soon. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336818